# Case Statement for MyPosts Query Not Working

Tags: wordpress

I'm stuck on query I am trying to write. My goal is to create 3 use cases depending on how many posts are in category 24 for a slider. For no posts in category 24, I'd like to hide all the code. For one post in category 24, I'd like to output HTML that styles the single post. For multiple posts, I'd like to output HTML that styles the posts in a slider.

My problem is that my code works fine if there are no posts and if there is one post, but it seems to get stuck if there are multiple posts. It just outputs the case for the one post. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    <div id="posts">
        <?php
    $myposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=-1&category=24');
    // Check to make sure you have an array, set the postcount to zero if you don't.
    if (is_array($myposts)) {
        $postcount = count($myposts);
    } else {
        $postcount = 0;
    }
    switch($postcount) {
        case 0:
            //  Do nothing, so no code here for no posts.
        break;
        case 1:
            // Code here for what you want to do if there is only one post.
?>
            <?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=24&posts_per_page=1'); ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="onefeatured-post">
    <ul id="onefeatured-post-list"><div class="onefeatured-post-image">
                <?php featured_post_image(); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="onefeatured-post-text">
                <h2 class="onefeatured-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="onefeatured-post-content"><?php limits(160, "Read more"); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </li></ul>
    <div class="onefeatured-post-nav">
        <div id="onefeatured-post-pages"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
        break;
        default:
            // Code here for what you want to happen if there is more than one post.
            include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured-posts.php');
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little more intuitive to uses normal conditionals instead:

```
<div id="posts">
  <?php
    $myposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=-1&category=24');

    if( ! empty( $myposts ) && 1 == count( $myposts ) ) {
        query_posts( $query_string . '&cat=24&posts_per_page=1' );

        if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  ?>
            <div class="onefeatured-post">
                <ul id="onefeatured-post-list">
                    <li>
                        <div class="onefeatured-post-image">
                            <?php featured_post_image(); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="onefeatured-post-text">
                            <h2 class="onefeatured-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <div class="onefeatured-post-content"><?php limits(160, "Read more"); ?></div>
                        </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="onefeatured-post-nav">
                    <div id="onefeatured-post-pages"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
  <?php
        endif;
      endwhile;
    } elseif( ! empty( $myposts ) ) {
        include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/featured-posts.php' );
    } else {
        echo "<p>No posts found</p></div>";
    }
  ?>
```

The first conditional will catch arrays of 1 and the 2nd conditional will catch array greater than 1, then we just have an `else` to catch empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am open to changing the code as you suggested. For some reason I am getting a syntax error when I try the code. Should I add an endif or endwhile or anything else?

Comment: @butterscotch yeah, looks like I missed a endif and endwhile in the first condotional. Im on mobile unfortunately so I cant fix it at this moment.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me with this! I added the endif and endwhile and no errors now !

Comment: And everything is working perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @butterscotch try changing the conditional to use count($myposts) == 1